# Qualitative study of differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, self-learning

Good morning everyone ,

I'd like to ask the following doubt within the exercise :

Study  $y'= \frac{x \cdot e^{y(x)}}{(y(x)-1)} $ .

After separable variables I obtain : $-ye^{-y}=\frac {x^{2}}{2} + C$

The doubt was (in the picture) : I'd like to know after the first two graph on the left (one of $-ye^{-y}$, one of $\frac {x^{2}}{2} + C$) how to properly put them in a sort of bijection, or at least gather them properly so that I could find the graph on the right, that is my final goal.

[image]Help would be appreaciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this MATHEMATICA script 

`gr = Table[
   If[c > 0, 
    ContourPlot[y E^-y + x^2/2 + c == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
     ContourStyle -> Red], 
    ContourPlot[y E^-y + x^2/2 + c == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
     ContourStyle -> Blue]], {c, -1, 1, 0.1}];
Show[gr]`

we can verify the results obtained analytically confirming that

$$
ye^{-y}+\frac{x^2}{2}+c = 0
$$

is an implicit function $y=y(x,c)$ only for $c \ge 0$ (blue curves). In red the results for $c < 0$

I hope this helps.

[image]